# Facebook auth screen different on iOS/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

I use the facebook-ios-sdk for my iPhone app and launch the authorization screen when the user push a button. But i always get a different authorization screen. I enabled the "enhanced auth dialog" in the advanced settings...

[image]

Other apps use this one:

[image]

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"167080433419201" andDelegate:self];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
   facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
   facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
   NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"user_about_me",nil];
   [facebook authorize:permissions];
}
```

Comment: in this code you have only give permission for @"user_about_me"
so it asks for only about you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i tried different permissions. But the authorization screen takes a while before it changed to the right one...

Answer (score 0):

OAuth requires user to login to get granted permissions if there are no permissions in their app privacy list.
After login and allowing the app permissions request, we can get **access_token** from the redirected url.

So your situation is you must login first and your ios test app may already exist on the facebbook app privacy list.

The second screen had already been loged in, but the first screen was not.
You should adopt the FBSessionDelegate to store the access_token & expiration date.

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

Comment: But why i get the first screen, and other apps get the seconds screen?

Comment: The second screen had already been loged in, but the first screen didn't.
Do the first app require to login on every launching time?
If yse, you should adapt the FBSessionDelegate to store the access_token & expiration date.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions that you set while authorizing the facebook.

this is just an example

```
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            @"user_likes", 
            @"read_stream",
            nil];
        [facebook authorize:permissions];
```

you can find more permission types here:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: which version of facebook api you are using?
and can you provide the code you have tried